# MBTile and its Layers Issue

Tags: ios, mbtiles

I am using `MBTiles` for one of my Apps. Client given 1 `MBTile` file and I need extract that MBTile file and get all  layers with in that MBTile file and and its layer Names I need

I am using the code below:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"myMBTILE" ofType:@"mbtiles"]];
    //     NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"control1" ofType:@"mbtiles"]];
offlineSource=[[RMMBTilesSource alloc]initWithTileSetURL:url ];

mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:_myView.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];

mapView.delegate = self;
mapView.zoom = 2;
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

[_myView addSubview:mapView];
```

I am very new to iOS. Please Help me

Comment: I think an MBTiles file does not contain layers. Do you mean zoom levels? What do you mean by "get all layers" Your code does not show any attempt to extract layers, you just initialize a RMMapView object. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes with particuler Zooming levels ,,  How can I do ti programmatically in ios